# A question regarding might be/might have been

Tags: grammar, tense

When I was reading, I encountered 2 sentences like these:

> 1. I went to his house last night, because I thought he might have the information I needed.
> 2. He thought the book might help him move on from the past.

In the first sentence, why didn't the writer use "I thought he might have had the information", and in the second sentence why not "might have been able to help", since they're both talking about past events?

I am a little confused here. Your useful answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the simple past with the past perfect. *Might* is already the simple past tense of *may,* and thus it agrees with the beginning of the first sentence, which uses the simple past *went.*

If you wanted to use *might have had* in the second part, you would need to change the first part to a past perfect as well:

> I had gone to his house that night, because I (had) thought he might have (had) the information I needed.

In this sentence, however, you can actually drop the subsequent *had*s because the first clause has already established the timeframe. To me, the most natural phrasing would be

> I had gone to his house that night, because I thought he might have the information I needed.

Also, *needed* could become *need* if you still need the information at the moment of speaking.

The second sentence is similar.

Comment: Thx for answering, m enlightened. But i still have a further question. i thought that the have + past participle here doesn't have a perfect meaning, and in addition to that, i was taught that 'might have been' speaks of something in the past. Could you please kindly provide further explanation? Thank you for answering.

Comment: In a strictly grammatical sense, *might* is the past tense of *may.* But as English has evolved, we've ended up with slightly different rules for **sentences** and for **indirect quotations.** So, `He thought there might be another door.` refers to the the past tense, whereas `There might be another door.` refers to the present. We could even combine the present-tense *might* with a past-tense *thinks*: `He thinks there might be another door.` Inside an indirect quotation, like "He thought _____," *might* is enough to satisfy the rule that the tenses should match.

Comment: And whether or not it's part of an indirect quotation, have + past participle *does* have a perfect meaning: `Have you eaten?` asks if you have completed eating. You are correct about *might have been ___ing* referring to the past, but note that that form doesn't appear in any of these examples.

Comment: This makes me a little more confused. Because sometimes we do use expressions like 'Deb was worried and thought she might have been pregnant." when describing past events. What's the difference? Is there a subtext to this sentence, which is that Deb had already been pregnant before she felt worried? Thx for ur patience n further explanation.

Comment: To my ears, `Deb was worried and thought she might have been pregnant.` is an unlikely sentence. It means it's September now, and we are talking about a moment in June at which something made Deb think that she *had been* pregnant in April-May but *wasn't* pregnant *anymore.* In other words, `Deb was worried in June: She hadn't thought that in April that she was pregnant, but now it looked like a pregnancy had ended in May (she had miscarried), meaning that she had been pregnant in April but didn't realize.`

Comment: This is a clunky sentence, and a more natural way to convey the meaning would be `Deb hadn't thought she was pregnant, but [xyz symptoms] made her worry she'd had a miscarriage.`

Comment: Perhaps the sentence you are looking for is `Deb was worried and thought she might have gotten pregnant,` in which case we are using *have + past participle,* not *have been + adj/__ing.* This sentence means, more simply, `Deb was worried she was pregnant.` (because she missed her period or something)

Comment: I went through all of your detailed explanations a couple of more times, and, pardon me for being slow-witted, I think this leads us back to the first incorrect expression 'I thought he might have had the information I needed.' Compared to "Deb thought she might have gotten pregnant.", I think they both employed have + past participle. So could u please elaborate on the reason why the first isn't correct? Sorry for pestering you. This has been bothering me for quite a long time, probably cuz there're no definite boundries between tenses in my mother tongue, Chinese.

Comment: The first sentence in the original post isn't incorrect. I'm saying it's not *necessary* to use "might have had." But it wouldn't be wrong to.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the point now. But you mentioned just now that whenever have + past participle is used, the sentence has a perfect meaning. Then why is 'Deb was worried and thought she might have gotten pregnant' the same as 'Deb was worried she was pregnant.' in the simple past without a perfect meaning?

Comment: In the first case, the action that has been completed is "getting pregnant." *Get pregnant* and *be pregnant* are different verbs.